# Galois group of splitting field over an infinite field of prime characteristic

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $p$ and the polynomial $P(x)= x^{2023}+x+1 \in K[x]$. Let $E$ be the splitting field of $P(x)$ over $K$. Prove that $E/K$ is a cyclic extension.

**My progress so far**: This is a problem in my final term two days ago. A given hint is to compare $E$ with the splitting field of $P(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. If $K$ is also a finite field, then the problem is reduced to prove that a finite extension of finite field is cyclic and I could do that. But I wonder how to approach when $K$ is an infinite field, for e.g: $K=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$.

I guess that there is a specific field homomorphism $\phi$ - just like the Frobenius in the case when $K = \mathbb{F}_p$ and show that $\text{Gal}(E/K)$ is generated but such $\phi$, but so far I can't think of any maps like that. Any hints are really appreciated.

Comment: You might need to treat the cases $p=7, 17$ (the prime factors of $2023$) separately.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes, I paid attention to that. But  I think it is just some technical issue, since most case $p$ will be coprime with $7,17$. But I have no idea how to deal with the genral case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be the roots of the polynomial in some fixed algebraic closure of $K$. Then $E=K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$. Define:

$$\varphi:\text{Gal}(K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)/K)\to\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F_p}(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)/\mathbb{F_p})$$

by restriction $\sigma\to\sigma|_{\mathbb{F_p}(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)}$. Verify that this is a well defined (i.e the restriction is indeed an automorphism of $\mathbb{F_p}(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$), injective group homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to confirm a little bit: I verified that $\sigma$ - when restriction to $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ - is an automorphism of  $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ by show that $\sigma$ maps $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_j$ in the set of roots and it fixes $K$, thus fixes $\mathbb{F}_p$. Is this enough?

Comment: @Tri Yes, that's it.